# RequiredFieldValidator with ValidationGroup doesn't validate

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator, validationgroup

Here's my markup:

```
Name: 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNewName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="NewDepartmentValidationGroup" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldtxtNewName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNewName"
    ErrorMessage="Required Field" /><br />
Description: 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNewDescription" runat="server"          
    ValidationGroup="NewDepartmentValidationGroup"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldtxtNewDescription" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txtNewDescription" ErrorMessage="Required Field" /><br />
<asp:Button ID="cmdCreate" runat="server" Text="Create"
     ValidationGroup="NewDepartmentValidationGroup" OnClick="cmdCreate_Click" />
```

When I remove ValidationGroup attribute, the behavior is as expected and the client side code warns that the field is required.

But when I specify ValidationGroup (as noted in the example above) and I click the button with the text boxes empty, the client side code does nothing, the button click event fires and the Page.IsValid equals true and my code proceeds, contrary to what is expected.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are missing Validation Group on the Validators.

There's no need to specify validation group on the controls(textboxes) instead specify the validation group on the validators and the button on which you want the valid data to be posted!

Try this one:

```
    Name: 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNewName" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldtxtNewName" runat="server"
     ControlToValidate="txtNewName" ValidationGroup="NewDepartmentValidationGroup" 
     ErrorMessage="Required Field" /><br />
Description: 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNewDescription" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldtxtNewDescription" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txtNewDescription" ErrorMessage="Required Field"
    ValidationGroup="NewDepartmentValidationGroup" /><br />
<asp:Button ID="cmdCreate" runat="server" Text="Create"
     ValidationGroup="NewDepartmentValidationGroup" OnClick="cmdCreate_Click" />
```

Comment: I've gotta get my eyes checked. Thank you for pointing out this silly mistake.

Answer (score 6):

try with ValidationGroup="NewDepartmentValidationGroup" in the validators not in textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNewName" runat="server"  />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldtxtNewName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNewName"  ValidationGroup="NewDepartmentValidationGroup"
            ErrorMessage="Required Field" /><br />
Description: 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNewDescription" runat="server"          
    />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldtxtNewDescription" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txtNewDescription" ErrorMessage="Required Field" ValidationGroup="NewDepartmentValidationGroup"/><br />

<asp:Button ID="cmdCreate" runat="server" Text="Create"
      ValidationGroup="NewDepartmentValidationGroup" OnClick="cmdCreate_Click" causesvalidation="true" />
```