# RequiredFieldsValidatior asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a page with two detailsView and I have tried to add a RequiredFieldsValidator for all fields and it worked fine but when I add the ValidationGroup the validation doesn't work at all

What is the problem

First DetailsView:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
        CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Username" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" 
           ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="50px" Width="267px" 
            style="margin-top: 0px; text-align: left;" 
           onitemupdated="DetailsView1_ItemUpdated" onitemdeleted="DetailsView1_ItemDeleted" 
           oniteminserted="DetailsView1_ItemInserted" DefaultMode="Insert">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" />
        <Fields>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username" SortExpression="Username">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>' 
                        ValidationGroup="1" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                        ErrorMessage="Required" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ForeColor="Red" 
                        ValidationGroup="1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Password">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Password") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Password") %>' 
                        Height="22px" ValidationGroup="1" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" 
                        ValidationGroup="1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <span ID="idControl">DetailsView1</span> - Field[1] - Password
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserType" SortExpression="UserType">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserType") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString ="<%$ConnectionStrings: ConnectionString %>" 
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("UserType") %>' ValidationGroup="1">
                    <asp:ListItem>--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>employee</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>doctor</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>student</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList> 
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="DropDownList4" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" 
                        InitialValue="--Select--" ValidationGroup="1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserType") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowInsertButton="True" />
        </Fields>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

Second DetailsView:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView4" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
            CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="St_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" 
            DefaultMode="Insert" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="50px" 
            Width="291px">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" />
            <Fields>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student ID" SortExpression="St_ID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("St_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("St_ID") %>' 
                            ValidationGroup="2"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" 
                            ValidationGroup="2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("St_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="120px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username" SortExpression="Username">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>' 
                            ValidationGroup="2"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" 
                            ValidationGroup="2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' 
                            ValidationGroup="2"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="TextBox4" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" 
                            ValidationGroup="2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nationality" SortExpression="Nationality">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Nationality") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Nationality") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" 
                            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Nationality") %>' ValidationGroup="2">
                        <asp:ListItem>--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Egypt</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Jordan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Lebanon</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Palestine</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Sudan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Syria</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>UAE</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yemen</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="DropDownList5" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" 
                            InitialValue="--Select--" ValidationGroup="2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Gender") %>' ValidationGroup="2">
                        <asp:ListItem>--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" 
                            InitialValue="--Select--" ValidationGroup="2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Major_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DateOfBirth" SortExpression="DateOfBirth">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateOfBirth") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="Date" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("DateOfBirth") %>' ValidationGroup="2"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" 
                            ValidationGroup="2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateOfBirth") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MobileNo" SortExpression="MobileNo">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MobileNo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MobileNo") %>' 
                            maxlength="10" ValidationGroup="2"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="TextBox7" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" 
                            ValidationGroup="2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <br />
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpresphone1" 
                            ValidationGroup="phone" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="TextBox5" 
                            runat="server" ErrorMessage="Phone Number should be 10 Digits (only numbers)." 
                            SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="^\d{10}$" Font-Bold="False" 
                            ForeColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MobileNo") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Major" SortExpression="Major_ID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Major_ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="MajorName" 
                            DataValueField="Major_ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Major_ID") %>' 
                            ValidationGroup="2"></asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="DropDownList2" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" 
                            InitialValue="--Select--" ValidationGroup="2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString ="<%$ConnectionStrings: ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Major_ID, MajorName FROM Major"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="School Graduation Year" 
                    SortExpression="School_Graduation_Year">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("School_Graduation_Year") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("School_Graduation_Year") %>' ValidationGroup="2"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="TextBox6" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" 
                            ValidationGroup="2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("School_Graduation_Year") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="School Grade" SortExpression="School_Grade">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("School_Grade") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("School_Grade") %>' 
                            ValidationGroup="2"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="TextBox7" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" 
                            ValidationGroup="2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("School_Grade") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Join Year" SortExpression="Join_Year">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Join_Year") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Join_Year") %>' 
                            ValidationGroup="2"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="TextBox8" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" 
                            ValidationGroup="2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Join_Year") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Email") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Email") %>' 
                            TextMode="Email" ValidationGroup="2"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="TextBox9" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" 
                            ValidationGroup="2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Email") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' 
                            ValidationGroup="2"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator15" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="TextBox10" ValidationGroup="2" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" 
                            ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowInsertButton="True" />
            </Fields>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        </asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RequiredFieldValidator with ValidationGroup doesn't validate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100230/requiredfieldvalidator-with-validationgroup-doesnt-validate)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100230/requiredfieldvalidator-with-validationgroup-doesnt-validate ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your validation group to your `CommandField`. E.g :

```
<asp:CommandField ValidationGroup="1" ButtonType="Button" ShowInsertButton="True" />
```

I'd also suggest using a more meaningful name for your Validation Groups

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use Like This..**

```
Name: 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNewName" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldtxtNewName" runat="server"
     ControlToValidate="txtNewName" ValidationGroup="NewDepartmentValidationGroup" 
     ErrorMessage="Required Field" /><br />
Description: 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNewDescription" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldtxtNewDescription" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txtNewDescription" ErrorMessage="Required Field"
    ValidationGroup="NewDepartmentValidationGroup" /><br />
<asp:Button ID="cmdCreate" runat="server" Text="Create"
     ValidationGroup="NewDepartmentValidationGroup" OnClick="cmdCreate_Click" />
```